# Get updates of inputs in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

i here,
I have some inputs in my dash-App.
I use dcc.Store to save the entries in inputs as dictionnary. e.g.

```
dcc.Store(id='old_data') 
@app.callback(
Output('old_data', 'data'),
[#here my inputs
]
)
def funtion(#here my inputs):
      old_data = {'time':'input1', ect...}
```

I want to do some optimizations in my callbacks depending on what dash Inputs has changed from the previous call
How can i get new_entries from my inputs and compare these with the old?
Is there a way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then what you can do here is set up your various inputs, and then the existing value in the `Store` as a `State` value. The input values will show you whatever the new values are, and you can compare that to what's stored in the old version of the `Store` before updating. Rough callback signature like:

```py
dcc.Store(id='old_data') 
@app.callback(
Output('old_data', 'data'),
[
    Input(),
    Input(),
],
[State('old_data', 'data')]
)
def funtion(input_1, input_2, old_store_value):
      # compare values and build return value
```

Comment: Thanks. And do you know if it possible to relaod the app after the comparison? like **if ...!=old_value_store: refresh layout** i tried with dcc.Location but the app is reloading all the time

Comment: I see you have a new question open for that, so I'll try to answer there.